# Writting data in EPC and User Memory Bank

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I have a R110Xi4 Zebra Printer and I'd like to write the EPC code (in EPC bank) and some other information in User Memory Bank. Is it possible? Write in two banks at same time is possible?

```
 My label has EPC of 240 bits and User Memory of 512 bits.
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I haven't tested this, but I think you would just issues the ^RF command multiple times for each memory location you want to write to.

The manual doesn't say that you can only issue this command once.

Check the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) for the associated parameters on page 392.